# Android - Distorted Camera Preview

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, preview, distortion

I am currently writing an android app which runs displays a circle drawable on the preview frame, runs edge detection and then takes a photo once the user lines up a coin perfectly in the circle.

For some reason (despite being fullscreen with no title etc.), I am started to realize the camera preview is every so slightly distorted. 
I have tried setting the previewsize to 480x640 while also setting the surfaceholder size to 480x640, however if I save the preview to bitmap and also take a photo, you can notice the distortion.

Has anybody else had this kind of problem / or have any ideas as to a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same issue.
Hopefully I found that `ApiDemos` includes a working example with Camera.
You can find it here: `com.example.android.apis.graphics.CameraPreview.`

I didn't digged the example, but I saw it's working fine just as my real camera, no distortion at all.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I might have to start building upon the sample app instead. I'd love to know what causes this problem though

Comment: It's something related to aspect ratio.